# Непонятная 413 ошибка в Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

Ситуация с комментариями и дополнениями описана на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/20298/). Так и не решил, помогите.

> Выдает `413 Request Entity Too Large` при загрузке файла через веб интерфейс.Директива в конфигах `client_max_body_size 100m`. Nginx работает, как фронтэнд к apache.

Comment: 1. Сперва, не могли бы вы определить "слабое" место? Например, добавить собственный скрипт загрузки файлов, но через nginx.2. Работает ли ваш сервер с файлами меньшего размера, например, до 1мб?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- post_max_size
- upload_max_filesize Есть предположение что как раз первую директиву вы и не поправили.